# React DND - Use different name prop for each compoents

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying one of react-dnd code examples: https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/01%20Dustbin/Single%20Target/Dustbin.js

```
const boxTarget = {
  drop() {
    return { name: 'Dustbin' }
  }
}

@DropTarget(ItemTypes.BOX, boxTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  isOver: monitor.isOver(),
  canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
}))

export default class Dustbin extends Component {
  ...
}
```

On the example, the `name` is hard coded. I need to use dynamic `name` so I passed a prop like this one

```
<Dustbin name="dustbin1" />
<Dustbin name="dustbin2" />
```

and changed the `boxTarget` into

```
const boxTarget = {
  drop() {
    return { name: this.props.name }
  }
}
```

However `this.props` became `undefined`, maybe because it's not inside the class. Is there any workaround so I can use different `name` for each `Dustbin` components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop function gets passed the props, but has no access to this (see http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target.html), so you just need to rewrite the boxTarget to look like:

```
const boxTarget = {
  drop(props) {
    return { name: props.name }
  }
}
```

And it will be able to return the name that you passed to it as a prop